# Swing equivalent of Android's GridView

Tags: java, android, swing

For my Java Swing app I want to display a grid of items, fixed to two columns, and for the elements (grid items), I want to use fixed height,  and if due to its height they don't fit, place a vertical scrollbar.

For anyone who knows a bit about Android development, is more or less what `GridView` does perfectly.

So, I'm trying to find a way to do that. I tried with a `JPanel` with `GridLayout` inside a `JScrollPane`, but in this case the elements get too much width and I also need a horizontal scrollbar, which definitely is not what I want.

So, what do you suggest?
Thank you.

Comment: GridLayout or GridBagLayout could be near.

Comment: I have solved my problem by using a JPanel with a GridLayout and by calling JPanel.setPreferredWidth(widthOfWindow, desiredHeight);